# Find two local averages within one SQL Server data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In the plant at our company there is a physical process that has a two-stage start and a two-stage finish.  As a widget starts to enter the process a new record is created containing the widget ID and a timestamp (DateTimeCreated) and once the widget fully enters the process another timestamp is logged in a different field for the same record (DateTimeUpdated).  The interval is a matter of minutes.

Similarly, as a widget starts to exit the process another record is created containing the widget ID and the DateTimeCreated, with the DateTimeUpdated being populated when the widget has fully exited the process.  In the current table design an "exiting" record is indistinguishable from an "entering" record (although a given widget ID occurs only either once or twice so a View could utilise this fact to make the distinction, but let's ignore that for now).

The overall time a widget is in the process is several days but that's not really of importance to the discussion.  What *is* important is that the interval when exiting the process is always longer than when entering. So a very simplified, imaginary set of sorted interval values might look like this:

> 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10

You can see there is a peak in the occurrences of intervals around the 3-minute-mark (the "enters") and another peak around the 7/8-minute-mark (the "exits").  I've also excluded intervals of 5 minutes to demonstrate that enter-intervals and exit-intervals can be considered mutually exclusive.

We want to monitor the performance of each stage in the process daily by using a query to determine the local averages of the entry and exit data point clusters.  So conceptually the two data sets could be split either side of an overall average (in this case 5.375) and then an average calculated for the values below the split (2.75) and another average above the split (8).  Using the data above (in a random distribution) the averages are depicted as the dotted lines in the chart below.

[image: Interval Chart]

My current approach is to use two Common Table Expressions followed by a final three-table-join query.  It seems okay, but I can't help feeling it could be better.  Would anybody like to offer an alternative approach or other observations?

[image: Table Structure]

```
WITH cte_Raw AS
     (
            SELECT
                   DATEDIFF(minute, DateTimeCreated, DateTimeUpdated) AS [Interval]
            FROM
                   MyTable
            WHERE
                   DateTimeCreated > CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)  -- Today
     )
   , cte_Midpoint AS
     (
            SELECT
                   AVG(Interval) AS Interval
            FROM
                   cte_Raw
     )
SELECT
           AVG([Entry].Interval) AS AverageEntryInterval
         , AVG([Exit].Interval)  AS AverageExitInterval
FROM
           cte_Raw AS [Entry]
           INNER JOIN
                      cte_Midpoint
                      ON
                                 [Entry].Interval < cte_Midpoint.Interval
           INNER JOIN
                      cte_Raw AS [Exit]
                      ON
                                 [Exit].Interval > cte_Midpoint.Interval
```

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand.  Can you please add some sample input data and your desired output from that data?

Comment: " In the current table design an "exiting" record is indistinguishable from an "entering" record (although a given widget ID occurs only either once or twice so a View could utilise this fact to make the distinction, but let's ignore that for now)." - you should absolutely stop ignoring this, and take the necessary steps to classify separate entries and exits. Otherwise you are faced with a potentially impossible problem.

Comment: You really should add an explicit field that indicates the type of the transition (entry vs exit), rather than trying to identify/guess it later after the fact. Once this information is available, the query is trivial. ........... Your query in the question is OK. The biggest problem with it is that it can return incorrect result if your data skews and your original assumptions are not valid anymore. You have at least 2 assumptions. 1) Entry and Exit durations never overlap 2) The dispersions of both Entry and Exit durations are similar, i.e. you have 3 +-1 and 8 +-1, not 3 +-1 and 1000 +-800.

Comment: @AakashM and VladimirBaranov - There is quite a bit of compiled C# code using the existing table definition to support the primary purpose of this Process; this Performance Monitoring is secondary.  If I can't get a reliable solution working based on the existing structure then we'll have to weigh up the cost/benefit of making the changes.

Comment: Beware that I discovered the DATEDIFF function returns an integer data type and the AVG function returns a data type inferred from the argument, hence another integer.  As all the code samples discussed involve multiple invocations of the AVG function there's a fair bit of rounding going on.

Comment: I overcame the rounding problem by implicitly casting the Interval data type:  `1.0 * DATEDIFF(minute, DateTimeCreated, DateTimeUpdated) as [Interval]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your query produces accurate results.  Your two `JOIN`s are producing a proliferation of rows, which throw the averages off.  They might look correct (because one is less than the other), but it you did counts, you would see that the counts in your query have little to do with the sample data.

If you are just looking for the average of values that are less than the overall average and greater than the overall average, then you an use window functions:

```
WITH t AS (
      SELECT t.*, v.[Interval],
             AVG(v.[Interval]) OVER () as avg_interval
      FROM MyTable t CROSS JOIN
           (VALUES (DATEDIFF(minute, DateTimeCreated, DateTimeUpdated))
           ) v(Interval)
      WHERE DateTimeCreated > CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
     )
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN t.[Interval] < t.avg_interval THEN t.[Interval] END) AS AverageEntryInterval,
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.[Interval] > t.avg_interval THEN t.[Interval] END) AS AverageExitInterval
FROM t;
```

Comment: Hmm...you're right Gordon, replacing the AVG functions in the final query with `SELECT *` shows there is a proliferation of rows.  +1  

I'll study the responses from yourself and others and comment more later.

Comment: As written your query fails to parse Gordon, primarily because you reference table v but it is undefined.  However your approach of using the CASE statement within the AVG function is a useful idea!

Comment: _(Just discovered this comment in a browser tab that I had started 2 weeks ago and then obviously got distracted and didn't post.)_  Gordon, I see you corrected the reference to the table v, however the query still doesn't parse.  SQL Server says _Invalid column name 'DateTimeCreated'_ and _Invalid column name 'DateTimeUpdated'_ on line 5.  I was a bit surprised as they are the correct names in MyTable - even prefixing them with t. didn't help.  It's like SQL can't see that table from within the `VALUES` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post my own answer as at the time of writing neither of the two proposed answers will run.  I have however removed the JOIN statements and used the CASE statement approach proposed by Gordon.

I've also multiplied the DATEDIFF result by 1.0 to prevent rounding of results from the AVG function.

```
WITH cte_Raw AS
     (
            SELECT
                   1.0 * DATEDIFF(minute, DateTimeCreated, DateTimeUpdated) AS [Interval]
            FROM
                   MyTable
            WHERE
                   DateTimeCreated > CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)  -- Today
     )
   , cte_Midpoint AS
     (
            SELECT
                   AVG(Interval) AS Interval
            FROM
                   cte_Raw
     )
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN cte_Raw.Interval < cte_Midpoint.Interval THEN cte_Raw.[Interval] END) AS AverageEntryInterval,
       AVG(CASE WHEN cte_Raw.Interval > cte_Midpoint.Interval THEN cte_Raw.[Interval] END) AS AverageExitInterval
FROM cte_Raw CROSS JOIN cte_Midpoint
```

This solution does not cater for the theoretical pitfall indicated by Vladimir of uneven dispersions of Entry vs Exit intervals, as in practice we can be confident this does not occur.